# Uniform distribution,probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Fix a positive integer $ b>0 $.

Let $ U\sim U[0,1] $ be uniformly distributed random variable, over the segment $[0,1]$.

Let $ (A_n)_n $ be a sequence of random variables, such that

$$ \mathbb{P}\left(U=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A_n}{b^n}\right)=1 .$$

Show that $ (A_n)_n $ are independent random variables, all uniform on the set $\{ 0,1,\ldots,b-1\}  $.

I tried to think of a solution, but couldnt find any idea.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The converse to this would be easier to prove.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: The statement doesn't look right.  You are trying to prove that two independent random variables $U$ and the sum are equal with probability $1$

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think the statement is correct. $A_n$'s are the coefficients in the expansion of $U$ to base $b$ and it is well known that these are i.i.d. I don't have a reference at the moment.

Comment: I didn't fully appreciate the definition of $A_n$.  Possible approach to your question.  If $A_k$ and $A_j$ for $j\ne k$ are dependent it should effect the uniformity of the distribution of $U$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you please guide me how to solve it?

Comment: $$
\text{For all } t\in\mathbb R,\quad \operatorname E(e^{itU}) = \operatorname E\left( \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{itA_n/b_n} \right) \qquad
$$
I might take a look at _Characteristic Functions_ by Eugene Lukacs. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

In order for $U$ to be uniform, each $A_k$ has to have a distribution $P(A_k=j)=\frac{1}{b}$ for $0\le j\le b-1$.  For any $n$ coefficient $A_k$, this means $P((A_{k1}=j1)\cap( A_{k2}=j2)....\cap (A_{kn}=jn))$$ =P(A_{k1}=j1)\times P( A_{k2}=j2)....\times P (A_{kn}=jn)=\frac{1}{b^n}$ which shows independence.

Comment: Well the first statement is exactly what I want to prove

Comment: If the equality doesn't hold, then for at least one $k$, that "digit" will distort uniform distribution of $U$.